# Multiple containers with resource/requests limits in pods on kubernetes return 0

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

*I don't know if this is a bug/issue or question.*

### Proposal

**Use case. Why is this important?**

For monitoring multiple containers with resource/requests limits in pods on kubernetes.

### Bug Report

**What did you do?**

I'm write a query to get a percentage of usage based on the maximum CPU usage and that we have max on the limits (resource and request) of the pod.

We have this problem affecting our query:

**1.** When we take a pod and it have 2 containers with configured resource/requets limits, it is not possible to take the value of resource/requests limits. **2.** Show the value of the pod (resource/requests), but it can have multiple replicas.

> max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="alpha",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s]) / on(pod) kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="alpha"}

**Error executing query:**`found duplicate series for the match group {pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{__name__="kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores", container="heapster-nanny", instance="kubestate-alpha.internal:80", job="k8s-prod-http", namespace="alpha", node="ip-99-990-0-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal", pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"}, {__name__="kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores", container="heapster", instance="kubestate-alpha.internal:80", job="k8s-alpha-http", namespace="alpha", node="ip-99-990-0-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal", pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side.`

We try solutions like: [[Using group_left to calculate label proportions]](https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions)

> sum without (container) (rate(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"}[1m]))

But if the value is set in the container, the result of the query is 0.
For not being able to calculate.

> kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"}

`kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="heapster", instance="kubestate-alpha.internal:80", job="k8s-alpha-http", namespace="alpha", node="ip-99-990-0-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal", pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"}                  0.084`
`kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="heapster-nanny", instance="kubestate-alpha.internal:80", job="k8s-alpha-http", namespace="alpha", node="ip-99-990-0-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal", pod="heapster-65ddcb7b4c-vtl8j"} 0.05`

Standard output for the `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores` command

**What did you expect to see?**

The sum of what is set in the containers in the pod.

**What did you see instead? Under which circumstances?**

Prometheus UI

**Environment**

- System information:

  Linux 4.4.0-1096-aws x86_64
- Prometheus version:

  v2.15.2

Comment: Is it supposed to be posted on github?

Comment: Hi @Vusal, not at the moment. It makes more sense to ask questions like this on the prometheus-users rather than in a GitHub issue. In the Prometheus Group and StackOverflow, more people are avaiable to potentially respond this question, and the whole communit can benefit from the answers provided.